# RESTful API nested resources - get all parent ids

Tags: restful-url

Though many question have been asked on nested urls and resources, I couldn't find an answer to this one:

I have two resources: user and blog.

A blog belongs to a user. A user can exist without any blogs.

I would like to create an endpoint that returns only users that have blogs (a distinct list).

I could use it to feed a select input on the front-end, to enable filter blogs per specific user, without listing users that don't have blogs.

What would be the URL for this endpoint?

```
/api/v1/blogs/users
```

or maybe

```
api/v1/users/?blogs=true
```

or something else?

Comment: It really depends on the standard you want to adopt for your API. Once you adopt a given structure, respect it throughout your project. 
Most guides will point to the first version as being more "standard", so to say.
I would recommend using URL parameters only for the returned format, not the returned data (i.e. language) though even that can be set through the HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0):

First one looks less obvious. You want to `GET` users, right? Go get users, with some parameter-defined restrictions. They aren't part nor property of general resource named `blogs`.